# Sencha app build native android package

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have generated sample app. I am able to compass compile. without packager.json configuration able to generate package. I need android package, so have done configuration in packager.json like this
 **"platform":"Android",
"sdkPath":"D:/Sench_Touch/android-sdk-windows",** but giving error in command prompt like below. How to resolve this issue? Can anybody tell me.Thank you

```
 [INF]           Completed compilation.
    [INF]           Processed remote file touch/sencha-touch.js
    [INF]           Processed local file app.js
    [INF]           Minified app.js
    [INF]           Minified resources/css/app.css
    [INF]           Generated app.json
    [INF]           Embedded microloader into index.html
    [INF]           Generating native package
    [INF]           Packaging your application as a native app to D:\Sench_Touch\sen
    cha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\native ...
    [ERR]           failed running native packager
    [ERR]           'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    Created directory D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\na
    tive\src\com\mycompany\myAppID
    Added file D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\native\sr
    c\com\mycompany\myAppID\STActivity.java
    Created directory D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\na
    tive\res
    Created directory D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\na
    tive\bin
    Created directory D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\na
    tive\libs
    Created directory D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\na
    tive\res\values
    Added file D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\native\re
    s\values\strings.xml
    Created directory D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\na
    tive\res\layout
    Added file D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\native\re
    s\layout\main.xml
    Added file D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\native\An
    droidManifest.xml
    Added file D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\native\bu
    ild.xml
    Added file D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\native\pr
    oguard-project.txt
    'C:\Users\User' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    ""D:/Sench_Touch/android-sdk-windows\tools\android" create project --target andr
    oid-10 --name MyApplication --activity STActivity --path "D:\Sench_Touch\sencha-
    touch-2.1.1-gpl\DemoApp\build\DemoApp\native\/" --package com.mycompany.myAppID"

    Could not run ant with error: 1
    Failed to package application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install your Sencha SDK tool in a directory with space names? I had the same problem when i installed my Sencha Cmd in Program Files. I installed it in C:/Sencha after this problem and it was fixed.

Comment: I have installed Sencha SDK tool with space names. in packager josn if i select device type ios simulator it will package without any issues. problem came for if select device type android. i have installed android sdk tool and set environment path also. but not able resolve this issue. can you tell me clearly how you resolve this issue. thank you

Comment: Just try it, android uses different tools and sencha sdk does some different stuff.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can´t build a native android package.
My sencha cmd is installed on "c:\sencha_cmd" and sdk tools on "c:\sencha_sdk".

What did you do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

run from your app folder

***sencha cordova init***

then change cordova.local.properties=android

save.

run 
***sencha app build native***

if you are using ST2.3.1 you will find app_name-debug.apk in ***cordova\platfomrs\android\ant-build*-*.apk*** folder :-)

Note:'You need to install cordova using ***npm install cordova -g***